# How do I find the NoData value of a TIFF on a Windows PC?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, windows, nodata

How do I find the nodata value of a tiff file on a Windows PC?

I've seen answers for Unix based systems [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274510/gdal-2-2-2-checking-all-nodata-values-in-a-directory-of-tifs-are-the-same), but not for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have GDAL installed you can open the command line and execute:

`"C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalinfo.exe" "file_path"`

It will tell you the nodata value (if there is one) within the results of this command