# Find NODATA values in TIF files using Python or QGIS

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, nodata

I have got about 7000 tifs in a directory. They all have the same defined NODATA value but not all of them contain cells with NODATA.

How to tell which ones have NODATA cells programmatically? Python is preferred but PyQGIS is also good.

Comment: You will find an answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274510/gdal-2-2-2-checking-all-nodata-values-in-a-directory-of-tifs-are-the-same